# Mongodb and Solr sync them together

Tags: database, mongodb, solr

I know it is a question asked over and over again, but unfortunately the various answers I have found on the net are old, fragmentary and confusing. The question is this:

*Is there a better world today to synchronize and index various collections in Mongodb to Apache Solr? and use solr as a search engine!*

Among other things, the ***data import handler*** seems deprecated in the next versions of solr. So what is the right way!

If possible a live example to import a database, several collections, a single collection in Apache solr!

Thanks, I think a clear answer in the year 2021 is convenient for helping a lot of people!

Comment: mongo-connector has been the suggested solutions for many years; is there any reason why that won't work? https://github.com/yougov/mongo-connector

Comment: maybe something more updated? mongo-connector is the only solution?

Comment: Don't assume that stable solutions are bad; the underlying ecosystem might not have changed in any relevant way. It just means that the current solution is well-tried. However, if you have issues with anything or it doesn't work with your setup, then sure, look for a different option. But mongoconnector is the suggested way as far as I know.